# upper triangle repeating the first row

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new with R and I need to solve this problem, if anyone could help me I'd be very grateful!
I have a dataframe as df1 shows and what I want is to repeat the first row in the upper triangule if it's the same ID:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), x1=c(6,6,6,3,3,3,2,2,2), x2=c(2,2,2,4,4,4,1,1,1), x3=c(4,4,4,10,10,10,7,7,7))
df1
```

This is the expected result:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), x1=c(6,0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0), x2=c(2,6,0,4,3,0,1,2,0), x3=c(4,2,6,10,4,3,7,1,2))
df1
```

I tried with df1[upper.tri(df1)] but it only leaves the dataframe values ​​and don't repeat the first round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this help

```
 df1[-1] <- unsplit(lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$ID), function(x) {x[lower.tri(x)] <- 0; diag(x) <- x[1,1]; x}), df1$ID)
```